# How to fetch data from multiple Database Links and insert it into specific tables using LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulkinsert, execute-immediate, sys-refcursor

I do have Oracle DataBase which has multiple DB_LINKS.

These DB_Links are stored in local (DB_LINKS_TBL)table.

The target is to synchronize the remote data with local machine.

I did the task using LOOP and REF_CURSOR insert but cannot insert REF_CURSOR into Table.

DB_LINKS_TBL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE DB_LINKS_TBL(DB_Link_Name VARCHAR2(50));
INSERT INTO DB_LINKS_TBL VALUES ('CAIRO_DB');
INSERT INTO DB_LINKS_TBL VALUES ('ALEX_DB');
```

PROCEDURE TO Synchronize data from CAIRO_DB , ALEX_DB:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR C_DB_LINK IS
         SELECT DB_Link_Name  FROM DB_LINKS_TBL ;
  L_Returnvalue SYS_REFCURSOR;
  L_Sql         VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
  --------------------#
  FOR db IN   C_DB_LINK LOOP
      ----------------
      L_Sql := 'SELECT Emp_Id, Emp_Name
                FROM   EMPS
                WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ''X''
                                   FROM   EMPS@'||db.DB_Link_Name||'  D
                                   WHERE  D.Emp_Id = S.Emp_Id) ';
      OPEN L_Returnvalue FOR L_Sql ;
      ----------------
      INSERT INTO EMPS   VALUES (L_Returnvalue);      
      COMMIT;
      ----------------
  END LOOP;
  --------------------#
END;
```

Comment: create an record type and use that instead of ref cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `SYS_REFCURSOR` for this.  Just do the INSERT directly

```
  L_Sql := 'INSERT INTO emps( emp_id, emp_name )
            SELECT Emp_Id, Emp_Name
            FROM   EMPS
            WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ''X''
                               FROM   EMPS@'||db.DB_Link_Name||'  D
                               WHERE  D.Emp_Id = S.Emp_Id) ';
  execute immediate l_sql;
```

Just taking a step back, though, are you certain that it makes sense architecturally to do this?  Oracle offers things like materialized views to replicate data between environments and has functionality for multi-master replication if individual rows can be modified on multiple source systems.  Rolling your own custom replication solution rarely makes sense.